# How to use keyfiles,for ZFS whole disk encryption?

Tags: encryption, bsd, key-authentication, zfs

Does anyone have a working implementation using keyfiles, preferably on SD Card, instead of a prompt for ZFS?  I know how to do this with linux LVM/LUKS.  In my opinion the FreeBSD full disk encryption solutions are WAY more secure, but I would really like to use keyfiles instead of getting prompted during boot.

I can't find a way to do it with google-magic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Update from January 2020

This question was answered in 2011, and the answer I gave pertains specifically to contemporary Solaris 11 behavior. **This does not apply to OpenZFS, illumos, or ZFS on Linux**.

That being said, the original answer remains, for posterity.

---

You have to create your key first. ZFS supports two types of file based keys. Hex, and raw. For this you can use `openssl` to generate the key.

```
openssl rand -out /media/stick/key 16
```

The `16` creates a 16-byte (i.e., 128-bit) key. For a 192-bit or 256-bit key use `24` or `32` respectively.

Then create your dataset as you normally would, specifying the key.

```
zfs create -o encryption=on -o keysource=raw,file:///media/stick/key rpool/encrypted
```

You can also use the `-hex` flag to `openssl rand` and `keysource=hex` for a human readable hex value in the file.

Comment: Thank you.  You have been most helpful.  Once I get it tested and working on my particular implementation I'll hit check.  Again, thanks.